# How to test if each value from a vector matches any value from a vector of strings?

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to use `str_detect` to test for each value from `fruit` whether there is a match in the vector `strings`.

```
fruit <- c("apple", "banana", "pear", "pinapple")
  strings <- c("apple", "app", "pear", "apple", "app", "pear", "apple", "app", "pear")
```

This does the job:

```
> map_chr(fruit, ~any(str_detect(.x, strings)))
[1] "TRUE"  "FALSE" "TRUE"  "TRUE"
```

But I was wondering whether there was a way to write it in a more concise form using the vectorization of `str_detect`. Something like:

```
  str_detect(fruit, strings)  

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Warning message:
In stri_detect_regex(string, pattern, opts_regex = opts(pattern)) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

But I am looking for an output of length `length(fruit)` instead of 9.

Comment: Not a solution, but because you're using `map_chr` you're getting logical values as strings, such as `"TRUE"` instead of `TRUE`. Use `map_lgl` to get logical values back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options to achieve a proper solution.

**Option#1:** Using `%in%` operator

```
fruit %in% strings

#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Option#2:** Using `str_detect`

```
library(stringr)

# Make sure to use \b around each word to avoid partial matching.
str_detect(fruit, pattern = paste("\\b",strings,"\\b", sep="", collapse = "|"))
#[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: Just to clarify: I actually meant to use partial matching so option 2 worked fine without `\\b`

Answer (score 1):

Banana and pineapple` should give you false as they are not in the strings:

```
str_detect(fruit,str_c("\\b(",strings,")\\b",collapse = "|"))

[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```